# Uploading multiple videos by multiple users on Server

Tags: java, video, file-upload, youtube-api

We have an urgent functionality in our project, where multiple users can ask their questions and queries in form of **videos files**(pre-recorded or record from application) and admin/sub admin can reply them in form of video file(recorded from application).

Considering the nature of application, there would be lot of data streaming on server and lot of storage required to kept the video files on server. So we are planning to store and kept the videos files separately on some centralized third-party server like "**YouTube**".

YouTube API allows to store and upload the videos files on their server but that is account specific. Is there any possibility that we can store all our application video files on the YouTube server in one centralized account?

I tried with YouTube Data upload API 2.0, but that require an authentication login (Google account) form the end-user who is uploading the video files. But i don't want that my end-users would be know where the files are going on. So, requirement is that i have to upload the videos(**without providing the Google account credentials**) in one centralized account(that would be kept at some property file). Is there any possible solution for this scenario?

If above solution fails, then please provide some alternatives considering the scenario.

One solution I found that i store the videos on some cloud server like "**Amazon S3**". does that would be good alternative?

Comment: Amazon S3 is a good solution, but there are (small) ongoing charges that you need to be aware of: <https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/>

Comment: Thanks Phil. I 'll look for this option.

Comment: But can i directly play the videos form Amazon S3(direct stream channel) as it supported in YouTube, as i don't want to first download the Video from Amazon and then play it on my server.